# linq between two datatables

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have two instances of sql server that are not linked, and the DBA will not link them.
Database 1 is on instance 1, database 2 is on instance 2

In database 1 is a Documentation table. This table does not exist on database 2.

I have the following query that runs on database 1 just fine:

```
    select name, modify_date from sys.objects where type = '@type' and modifydate >= '@date' and not exists (select column from documentationtable where name = sys.objects.name and inserteddate > sys.objects.modifydate and objecttype = @objecttype) order by modify_date
```

I have this query split into two separate queries now.

```
    select name, modify_date from sys.objects where type = @type and modifydate >= @modifydate order by modify_date
```

and

```
    select column from documentationtable where name in (@CompareString)
```

Each of the two above queries are populating two separate datatables. I'm trying to emulate the first query in linq or some other means to get the correct information returned, and so far I've not had any success.

Thinks to keep in mind: I cannot modify the database. I cannot link the two instances (or this would not be an issue).

Does anyone have any other ideas?

The point of this is to return a list of items that have been modified in the database to document why they have been modified to stay within ISO compliance. I am working in VB.Net using the 3.5 framework.

Comment: Do you need to use datatables? You could load both sets of data into a simpler data structure -- List(Of AnonymousType) -- and combine them together.

Comment: I have vague recollections that you have to convert the DataTables to DataSets first.

Comment: I don't have to use datatables. I can convert it to whatever. The "not exists in (select...)" is what is throwing me for a loop right now.

Comment: Please format this without horizontal scrollbars. Also make clear which of the two separate queries runs where (I think bb2 and db1, respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing this:

I loaded all the objects from the system table based on type.
From there I created a stored procedure to look at the table where we are storing the data. If an object is returned, that means it exists in the table already with the parameters I specified, and I don't want to save it, so I move to the next item that was loaded in the sys.objects datatable.

From there, I'm able to determine what is needed and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote a while back.  It's not production code, it's just messing about.

```
DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
dataTable1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dataTable1.Columns.Add("text", typeof(string));
dataTable1.Rows.Add(1,"one");

DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
dataTable2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dataTable2.Columns.Add("text", typeof(string));
dataTable2.Rows.Add(1, "fred");

List<testType> joinedData = (
                from dataRow2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
                join dataRow1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                 on (int)dataRow2["id"] equals (int)dataRow1["id"]
                select new testType()
                {
                    Col1 = (int)dataRow1["id"],
                    Col2 = (string)dataRow2["text"]
                }).ToList();

foreach (testType item in joinedData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello - " + item.Col1.ToString() + " --- " + item.Col2 );
}
```

It works.  I see the expected results in the console.  It might give you some ideas.

Comment: I actually believe something like that will work. The question is, how do I get items that list in datatable1 and do not exist in datatable 2?

Comment: @Bigdaddyduergar Enumerables have an Except method that takes another Enumerable and leaves only the unmatched members.